# Android Espresso: click() on a TextView

Tags: android, android-espresso

I do have a TextView with an onClick-method defined in xml. In the app everything works fine and as expected, but I don't get it to work via Espresso.

I try

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_text_view)).perform(click());
```

but the according method is never executed. How can I achieve this?

this is my TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/letter_personal_data"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:background="@drawable/letter_border_background"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="showPersonalDataDialog"
    android:padding="@dimen/letter_standard_padding"
    android:text="@string/letter_personal_data"
    android:textAppearance="@style/LetterTextOrange"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and this is how my test looks like:

```
@Test
public void myFirstTest() {
    onView(withId(R.id.letter_personal_data)).check(matches(notNullValue()));
    onView(withId(R.id.letter_personal_data)).perform(click());
    onView(withId(R.id.personal_data_name_text)).check(matches(notNullValue()));
}
```

Comment: The line seems correct. If you try to debug the test can you check if the method is launched and what happens on this line?

Comment: the method is called - but nothing happens there; it doesn't fail or something, but the dialog which should appear doesn't

Comment: It is quite strange. Can you debug the onClickListener method or can you insert a log inside the method called by the click?

Comment: methods like ```onCreate``` and ```onPostResume``` in my activity are called - but not my clickListener-method.

Comment: It is a silly question (sorry).. but are you sure that the onClickListener is attached to the text_view?

Comment: there are no silly questions :) I added some code, so yes, the ```onClickListener``` is on the ```TextView``` for sure...

Comment: could you add a log from test? I don't know what kind of problem it is?

Comment: do you still face the problem?

Comment: @piotrek1543 yes, unfortunately

Comment: @swalkner SoI see two solutions: to change `TextView` with `Button` with transparent background (it would still look like `TextView`, but it would be a button) and change a method of catching a view (you're already catching it by id, try by textView text)

Comment: You have a lot attributes for textView - make it as simple as possible, just for now, for tests. Check if TextView is not nested, then you can call TexView by parent

Comment: add whole xml layput

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
onView(withText(R.string.letter_personal_data)).check(matches(notNullValue()));
    onView(withText(R.string.letter_personal_data)).perform(click());
```